# How to add a space to the left of bootsrap row?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like to know what is the best way to add space to the left side of 
a bootsrap row, which uses col-sm-*.
I was able to achieve it using an empty div as shown below.

```
           <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-1" >
                   <!-- I want to remove this div -->
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2" >
                    Text1
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    Text2
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    Text3 
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    Text4
                </div>
           </div>
```

But that's not a nice way. How we can do it without using empty div?

Comment: style="margin-left:10px"

Comment: add css :  col-md-offset-2

Comment: You could look at [Offsetting columns](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code:

```
.col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-1
```

in the second div as below:

```
<div class="row">                
            <div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-1" >
                Text1
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                Text2
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                Text3 
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                Text4
            </div>
       </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Bootstrap's Offsetting Column](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting) classes to achieve this by applying class `col-sm-offset-1` on first column as follows:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-1" >
    Text1
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    Text2
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    Text3 
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    Text4
  </div>
</div>
```